# Probabilty of "clumps" in a grid

Tags: probability

I am creating a grid where each element of the grid is picked randomly from a finite set of $N$ elements:

[image]

I'm wondering about the probability to have "clumps" (groups of contiguous identical elements).

My possibly naïve answer is that to get a clump of $k$ elements there is a probability $1/N$ that each element of the clump is the same as the first one, so the probability of a clump of size $k$ around a given position is $P_c = (1/N)^{k-1}$.

This probability is quite low, but the probability that it happens anywhere in a $X \times Y$ grid is $P = P_c \times X \times Y$ so is significant.

However, I'm not convinced that this is all there is to it. For instance, around a position, there are four $2 \times 2$ squares that include this position, so their probabilities of existence would also overlap? Or I should only be considering clumps with the same "origin" (for instance, bottom-left corner)  and the formula should include margins since for instance there cannot be a $2 \times 2$ square clump with is bottom-left corner along the right or top edges?

Am I overlooking something?

Comment: +1 for the graphic.

Comment: As to the question, I suggest simulating it to get a numerical result before trying to solve it analytically.

Comment: Should add that the definition of "clump" isn't entirely clear (to me, anyway).  I would define it as requiring horizontal or vertical connections...two diagonally adjacent cells can't form a clump on their own.  And I would have said that a clump of size $k$  contained smaller clumps as well, though perhaps your intent was different.

Comment: As a reference for ideas, check out Putnam 2004 A5, which says that when $N=2$, the expected number of connected components is $> mn/8$ (where $m, n$ are the dimensions of the rectangle). Try modifying the solution to a general $N$.

Comment: This question belongs to the area of **percolation theory**. Based on the known results, I believe that the exact answer is quite unlikely to exist for your question. Perhaps the best we can hope for is a qualitative description of the size distribution of a cluster. Since the percolation threshold $p_c$ for the site percolation on $\mathbb{Z}^2$ is known to exceed $0.5$, the subgraph for each of the "color" lies in the subcritical regime (unless $N=1$), meaning that the cluster size distribution has exponential tail.